# File download with android

Tags: android, popup, download

I am trying to save a file from the web to my Android device, but I do not know how to do it. The URL address opens a blank page and a popup download box with the file that I want to download so I can choose where to save it.

My problem is that I do not know how to manage that box in order to download the file. It is not like I want to download something that is shown on that page because the page is blank. So I cannot use this code :

```
         Context context = thisClass.this;
         Drawable image = ImageOperations(context,
          "http://android.okhelp.cz/images/adictionary/ad_4.png"
          ,"image.jpg");
         ImageView imgView;
         imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.idImageView);
         imgView.setImageDrawable(image);

private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could point me where to start looking or gave me a solution.

Comment: Do you not just have a direct link to the file? If so, you can download it and save it on the SD card or even in a database.

Comment: no, I can't download the file using the phone because that site has a mobile version that doesn't allow me to download that file. I can only download it using my computer and then from the computer transfer it to my phone. But I want to avoid this if possible..

Comment: I'm not talking about the link to the site, I'm talking about a direct link to the file. Can you show me the link of the website and what file you're trying to download?

Comment: No, I do not have a direct link to the file..I cannot show you the specific link because it is private but I will try to find another one if possible :)

Comment: It is the same as when you download the ics file from your facebook account by exporting your events. It gives you a link, you access it, and then it opens a blank page and a download box with the ics file. Hope it helps to give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!

```
           File card2= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
           File dir2= new File (card2.getAbsolutePath()+"/MyFiles");
            dir2.mkdirs();
           new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(your_url_here-this_is_a_string)).getEntity().writeTo(
            new FileOutputStream(new File(dir2,your_file_on_sdcard-this_is_string)));
```

This is also surrounded by try/catch. And remember to insert the protocol before the address or it won't work! 
Hope it helps!