# Download .txt file from internet

Tags: android, url, text, storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File download with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645166/file-download-with-android)

How do I download a .txt file from the internet at a given URL and save it to the phone in Android? It can be saved to either internal storage, SD storage, or anywhere really accessible for the app to use.

The URL I have been using for testing with loading URL WebViews is http://base.google.com/base/products.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. It downloads the file to `sdcard/Download/products.txt`. You can change it below.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://base.google.com/base/products.txt");
    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
    conexion.connect();
    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    File testDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download");
    if (!testDirectory.exists()) {
        testDirectory.mkdir();
    }
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(testDirectory + "/products.txt");
    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    long total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        int progress_temp = (int) total * 100 / lenghtOfFile;
        /*publishProgress("" + progress_temp); //only for asynctask
        if (progress_temp % 10 == 0 && progress != progress_temp) {
            progress = progress_temp;
        }*/
        fos.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    is.close();
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERROR DOWNLOADING", "Unable to download" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: You referenced an unknown variable `count` after initializing the variable `progress`. Am I safe to assume `count` should be `progress`?

Comment: Sorry! Add `int count;` where it can be accessed. Edited my answer!